# How to define config file syntax for: vlc --config [string]

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player

Does anyone know about `vlc --config` syntax?
I'm trying to pass some parameters in cli to a file, harnessing that vlc provide a `--config` parameter.

If I have a cli which works such as

```
./vlc --no-drop-late-frames --sout-ts-pcr=30 decklink://
```

I would like to know how to define **vlc.cfg** to invoke

```
./vlc --config vlc.cfg decklink://
```

Because I read that driver should be outside config file.

I've tried without success defining vlc.cfg as follows:

```
no-drop-late-frames
sout-ts-pcr=30
...
```

Any clue, please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried checking VLC wiki? Here's something that [might help](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/)

Comment: Yes, and there's no example for vlc config file syntax at this wiki